# Why is my Curl command not executed?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm working on a Bash script that will bring up to speed my shell after a fresh installation.

```
main()
{
    #
    #   By default we assume the terminal doesn't support colors
    #
    RED=""
    GREEN=""
    YELLOW=""
    BLUE=""
    BOLD=""
    NORMAL=""

    #
    #   Check  if we are connected to a terminal, and that terminal
    #   supports colors.
    #
    if which tput >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            ncolors=$(tput colors)
    fi

    #
    #   Set the colors if we can
    #
    if [ -t 1 ] && [ -n "$ncolors" ] && [ "$ncolors" -ge 8 ]; then
        RED="$(tput setaf 1)"
        GREEN="$(tput setaf 2)"
        YELLOW="$(tput setaf 3)"
        BLUE="$(tput setaf 4)"
        BOLD="$(tput bold)"
        NORMAL="$(tput sgr0)"
    fi

    #
    #   Only enable exit-on-error after the non-critical colorization stuff,
    #   which may fail on systems lacking tput or terminfo
    #
    set -e

################################################################################

    printf "${YELLOW}"
    echo ''
    echo '    ____             __   ___  _____        __  '
    echo '   / __ )____ ______/ /_ |__ \/__  /  _____/ /_ '
    echo '  / __  / __ `/ ___/ __ \__/ /  / /  / ___/ __ \'
    echo ' / /_/ / /_/ (__  ) / / / __/  / /__(__  ) / / /'
    echo '/_____/\__,_/____/_/ /_/____/ /____/____/_/ /_/ '
    echo ''
    echo ''
    printf "${NORMAL}"

################################################################################

    #
    #   Find out if Zsh is already installed
    #
    CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED=$(grep /zsh$ /etc/shells | wc -l)

    #
    #   Check to see if Zsh is already installed
    #
    if [ ! $CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED -ge 1 ]; then
        sudo apt-get -y install zsh
    fi

    #
    #   Clean the memory
    #
    unset CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED

################################################################################

    #
    #   Remove the previous config file, so we know we start from scratch
    #
    rm ~/.zshrc &&

    #
    #   Removing unnecessary Bash files
    #
    rm ~/.bash_history 2> /dev/null &&
    rm ~/.bash_logout 2> /dev/null &&
    rm ~/.bashrc 2> /dev/null &&
    rm ~/.bash_sessions 2> /dev/null &&
    rm ~/.sh_history 2> /dev/null &&

################################################################################

    #
    #   Download the configuration file
    #
    curl -fsSL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidgatti/my-development-setup/master/08_Zsh_instead_of_Bash/zshrc" >> ~/.zshrc

    #
    #   Get the name of the logged in user
    #
    USER_NAME=$(whoami)

    #
    #   Get the home path for the logged in user
    #
    HOME_PATH=$(getent passwd $USER_NAME | cut -d: -f6)

    #
    #   Add a dynamic entry
    #
    echo 'zstyle :compinstall filename '$HOME_PATH/.zshrc'' >> ~/.zshrc
}

main
```

I did run `Bash -x` and all works. But `curl` is nowhere to be seen in the resulting trace. What I tried:

- adding curl in a variable
- using eval
- setting `"` in 3 different ways
- etc.

## Question

I want to download a file unsigned `curl` inside the bash script that I linked to, where the bash script will be executed in the following way:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidgatti/my-development-setup/master/08_Zsh_instead_of_Bash/install.sh)"
```

## sh -x output

If I run

```
sh -cx "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidgatti/my-development-setup/master/08_Zsh_instead_of_Bash/install.sh)"
```

This is the output.

```
+ main
+ RED=
+ GREEN=
+ YELLOW=
+ BLUE=
+ BOLD=
+ NORMAL=
+ which tput
+ tput colors
+ ncolors=256
+ [ -t 1 ]
+ [ -n 256 ]
+ [ 256 -ge 8 ]
+ tput setaf 1
+ RED=
+ tput setaf 2
+ GREEN=
+ tput setaf 3
+ YELLOW=
+ tput setaf 4
+ BLUE=
+ tput bold
+ BOLD=
+ tput sgr0
+ NORMAL=
+ set -e
+ printf
+ echo

+ echo     ____             __   ___  _____        __
    ____             __   ___  _____        __
+ echo    / __ )____ ______/ /_ |__ \/__  /  _____/ /_
   / __ )____ ______/ /_ |__ \/__  /  _____/ /_
+ echo   / __  / __ `/ ___/ __ \__/ /  / /  / ___/ __ \
  / __  / __ `/ ___/ __ \__/ /  / /  / ___/ __ \
+ echo  / /_/ / /_/ (__  ) / / / __/  / /__(__  ) / / /
 / /_/ / /_/ (__  ) / / / __/  / /__(__  ) / / /
+ echo /_____/\__,_/____/_/ /_/____/ /____/____/_/ /_/
/_____/\__,_/____/_/ /_/____/ /____/____/_/ /_/
+ echo

+ echo

+ printf
+ wc -l
+ grep /zsh$ /etc/shells
+ CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED=2
+ [ ! 2 -ge 1 ]
+ unset CHECK_ZSH_INSTALLED
+ rm /home/admin/.zshrc
```

I personally don't see `curl` being executed

Comment: Don't make us chase links: post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Sorry for letting you chase, fixed.

Comment: What do you mean by "curl is nowhere to be seen"?

Comment: When I run it with `-x` all the commands show up, but curl is not there. For example the RM commands won't be displayed because I'm forwarding any error output to `/dev/null` but I'm not doing that with `curl` at least I think :)

Comment: You mean the curl command after the comment "Download the configuration file"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have no `~/.zshrc` file, therefore `rm ~/.zshrc` exits with a non-zero value. Since `rm ~/.zshrc` is the first command in a long list of commands chained with `&&`, none of the following commands are executed. `curl` is the last command of this list.

Solution #1: use `rm -f` instead of `rm` or don't terminate your lines with `&&`.

Moreover, you have put `set -e` just before your shinny banner. This makes your script exit at the first command that fails unexpectedly. Thus, removing `&&` won't be enough.

Solution #2: use `rm -f` or terminate your `rm` lines with `|| true` or `|| :`

Conclusion: change all your `rm foo 2> /dev/null &&` to `rm -f foo`

Comment: It worked, thank you very much :) a) I complexity forgot about `set -e` and was wonder gin what it is not crashing, and I thought that doing `2> /dev/null` will suppress any error, and keep going. The `-f` works perfectly. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear as to what you're having trouble with, but to save a file to which you have a URL:

```
curl -o /path/to/output-file http://www.example.com/path/to/the/file
```

To live very dangerously and run a presumed script in a `bash` shell:

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL http://www.example.com/path/to/script-that-quietly-installs-a-rootkit-for-you)"
```

Comment: Updated my question.